# java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack_Exception Details:_ Location:_ org/apache/commons/mail/Email.buildMimeMessage

Tags: java, email, liferay

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
```

Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/commons/mail/Email.buildMimeMessage()V @176: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'javax/mail/Multipart'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @176
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/commons/mail/Email' }
    stack: { 'javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage', 'javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart' }

```
public Email sendAppacheEmail(){
     email=new MultiPartEmail();
    try {
        email.setFrom("from");
        email.addTo("to");

        email.setHostName("host");

        email.setSmtpPort(587);


        email.setSubject("subject");
        email.setMsg("Test Body");
        email.setAuthentication(username, password);
        email.buildMimeMessage();
        email.send();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


   module.framework.properties.org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=\
    __redirected,\
    com.liferay.aspectj,\
    com.liferay.aspectj.*,\
    com.liferay.portal.servlet.delegate,\
    com.liferay.portal.servlet.delegate*,\
    com.sun.ccpp,\
    com.sun.ccpp.*,\
    com.sun.crypto.*,\
    com.sun.image.*,\
    com.sun.jmx.*,\
    com.sun.jna,\
    com.sun.jndi.*,\
    com.sun.mail.*,\
    com.sun.management.*,\
    com.sun.media.*,\
    com.sun.msv.*,\
    com.sun.org.*,\
    com.sun.syndication,\
    com.sun.tools.*,\
    com.sun.xml.*,\
    com.yourkit.*,\
    javax.validation,\
    javax.validation.*,\
    jdk.*,\
    sun.*,\
    weblogic.jndi,\
    weblogic.jndi.*,\
    javax.xml.*,\
    javax.mail.*,\
    javax.Transport.*,\
    javax.mail.internet.*,\
    org.apache.commons.mail.*
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you add such generic libraries and packages like xml, mail etc to the bootdelegation? Sounds like this is a bad solution to an unnamed underlying problem. Remove the nonstandard bootdelegation, and start by working on the dependencies of your plugin

Comment: I have removed last four packages but now issue is:
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.sun.mail.util.PropUtil.getBooleanSessionProperty(Ljavax/mail/Session;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current class, javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) for the method's defining class, com/sun/mail/util/PropUtil, have different Class objects for the type javax/mail/Session used in the signature

Comment: That's good. It means that you're bringing along your own javamail classes, while the runtime uses different ones. How do you declare your dependencies? (maven? gradle? post your buildfiles) Potentially your bnd.bnd as well. Versions, steps to reproduce, preferably in a minimal example like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

To reproduce it, you need a simple liferay plugin portlet and configure the email details same as above code and send, It is just a basic email send function.

Comment: Comments are hard to read. Please edit your question

Comment: I Understand , i'm new in stackoverflow but, I have changed the code and update the issue. Kindly take a look on that, it might give you more information.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60194916/javax-mail-messagingexception-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-email-smtp-us-eas

Comment: almost done: just don't post a new question, rather edit your existing question with that information