# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, port: 25;

Tags: java, email, liferay, jakarta-mail, liferay-7

public void emailTest() {

```
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"); 
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
    properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
    try{
    Session session=Session.getInstance(properties);

    Message msg=new MimeMessage(session);  

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@gmail.com", "Test"));
    msg.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("test@gmail.com", "Test"));
    msg.setSubject("Test Subject");
    msg.setText("Test Mail");
    msg.saveChanges();
    Transport transport=session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect("username","password");
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

    transport.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

POM : com.sun.mail javax.mail 1.5.2 provided

DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4ea

DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/javamail.providers (No such file or directory)

DEBUG: !anyLoaded

DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers

DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers

DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers

DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}

DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}

DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map

DEBUG: !anyLoaded

DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map

DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/javamail.address.map (No such file or directory)

DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]

DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false

DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", port 25, isSSL false

Answer (score 0):

You're using an ancient version of JavaMail; please update if possible.

If you're running your JavaMail program within AWS, note that AWS
has restrictions on how you use JavaMail and what SMTP host you can
connect to.  Consult their documentation for details.  (Sorry, I
don't have the link.)

If you're running outside of AWS, see the JavaMail FAQ for [tips on
debugging connection problems](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).  Most likely you're behind a firewall that's preventing you from connecting directly.